# Compare Long timestamp to Oracle timestamp

Tags: java, oracle, date, timestamp

I'm trying to compare a timestamp like
`Long tms = 1666682820002` in millisec by using
`Instant date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(tms)` to a date which is saved in Oracle db with this format **25-Oct-22 09.27.00,000000000** - the last 6 digits are always zero.
The column in the Oracle Db has been declared as Timestamp with 9 as fractional_seconds_precision.

I've tried to convert the Long value to Instant but somehow I don't have the precision I'm looking for - I obtain   **2022-10-25T07:27:00.002Z** - , thus when I search by this Instant value in the UPDATE query I don't find any records.

Is there a better way of solving this?

I've also considered transforming the Long date in Timestamp, adding the missing microseconds and nanoseconds as zero, convert into a String and comparing them with what's in the db.

Thank you

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type of your Oracle DB column?

Comment: What is the exact type of the field in the database? What have you tried?

Comment: The column in the Oracle db has been declared as Timestamp

Comment: Do not retrieve the timestamp as a string from your Oracle database. For most databases you should retrieve a `LocalDateTime`, and you’d better know what time zone was understood, or you can’t do anything with it anyway. Some say that no Oracle JDBC driver supports JDBC 4.2 anyway, so you may need to retrieve an old-fashioned `java.sql.Timestamp`, which you may in turn convert to a modern `Instant`. For the millisecond value `Instant.ofEpochMilli()` works, I can’t guess what you may have done wrong there.

Comment: @llandino And the *[(fractional_seconds_precision)]* of `TIMESTAMP` type in Oracle? See [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6).

Comment: FYI, the `TIMESTAMP` column in Oracle DB is the **wrong type to use to record a moment**, a specific point on the timeline. This Oracle type is akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, and maps to Java class `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque the [(fractional_seconds_precision)] is 9 (but the last 6 digits are always 0, not sure why there is this precision if not used), so when i try to compare my Instant (obtained by Instant.ofEpochMilli()) with the Oracle Timestamp in the db, I don't have the same precision, so I don't find the record to update

Comment: @llandino These details would have been nice to have in the body of your Question *before* posting and others answering.

Comment: @BasilBourque My bad, i've added as many details as possible to the question.

Comment: `Instant` always has a precision of 8 decimals of fraction of second (AKA nanoeconds). Its `toString`method may leave out decimals that are zero, which may have fooled you. And `Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_666_682_820_002L)` yields `2022-10-25T07:27:00.002Z` (with the last 6 decimals, the zeroed, not printed).

Comment: @OleV.V. ok got it, then it would be enough just to use the Instant value in the UPDATE query, although is the first thing I've tried and the comparison failed :/

Comment: It’s about 25 years ago I accessed Oracle database from Java, so won’t try to help there myself. If you post a [mre], I hope and think that someone can.

Comment: @llandino The `Instant` class is not mapped to any SQL type in JDBC.

Comment: So thank you both, I'll try to use LocalDateTime, I hope I'll have more luck with that @OleV.V. and BasilBourque

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the part of your question about a count of what appears to be milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z…

Call [`Instant.ofEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_666_682_820_002L ) ;
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/lDM8Di).

> 2022-10-25T07:27:00.002Z

If you want to clear the fractional second, truncate.

```
Instant instantTrunc = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

To search in the database, use the `java.time.OffsetDateTime` class that maps to the SQL standard type of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instantTrunc.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieve from database column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Get the count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Beware of data loss, as this ignores the microseconds/nanoseconds available in an `Instant` object.

```
long epochMilli = odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```

Comment: I do not see a reason why one should DV this answer.